# Como hago para que los subtítulos salgan en google asi como salen en firefox?

Tags: html5, video

Tengo unos videos en un proyecto html. Al ponerle subtítulos en google no salen pero en firefox si:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>


</head>
<body>

<video class='js-player' controls playsinline>
  <source src="fin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="The Simpsons - 29x10 - Haw-Haw Land.HDTV.KILLERS.en.srt.vtt">
  <track kind="captions" label="Español" srclang="es" src="The Simpsons - 29x10 - Haw-Haw Land.HDTV.KILLERS.en.srt.vtt" default>
</video>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: el kind no es `kind="subtitles"` ?

Comment: sip... muchas gracias.. se me fue..